# Style multiple elements when hovering image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
 render() {
   return (
   <div className="Section">
     <h1>Welcome to my Projects </h1>

     <ul className="Projects">
       {this.state.Projects.map(project => (
         <li key={project._id} className="ProjectsShowcase">
           {" "}
          // when i hover my mouse over this image i want it to have the same effect on 
             another button aswell 
          <img className="ProjectImage" src={project.image} alt=" of Project" />
          <button
            className="ProjectLiveVersionButton"
            disabled={!project.liveVersion}
            onClick={() => window.open(project.liveVersion)}
          >
            Live version
          </button>

        //this is the button i want to change when hovering image 
             <button 
            className="ProjectCodebutton" onClick={() => window.open(project.Code)}>
            Code{" "}
          </button>
       //this is the button i want to change when hovering image 
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
   );
  }
}
```

I tried giving the elements an ID instead of className but doesn't work

This is the CSS for the elements. I have tried adding .Section class before the elements in CSS and tried with  ~ + >

```
  // i have given the same styling to the image but i want the button to get bigger aswell 
     using this Css
 .ProjectImage:hover  .ProjectCodeButton {
 -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm using the `.ProjectImage:hover ~ .ProjectCodeButton` should work since `.ProjectCodeButton` is just its general sibiling, can't reproduce it the same as your example code, but this is the demo:

```css
.ProjectImage:hover,
.ProjectImage:hover~.ProjectCodeButton {
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<img class="ProjectImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" />
<button>Live version</button>
<button class="ProjectCodeButton">Code</button>
```

Comment: I just noticed i  had typed "ProjectCodebutton" instead of "ProjectCodeButton" with a Uppercase B in button.